# Able to compile, but not upload

Tags: troubleshooting

The board is BTT SKR v1.1.
I know the board is connected with COM3. I get the Avrdude 500 timeout.
I am using VS Code, and am close, but need to know exactly what changes to make in config/adv.

Comment: I have made some progress by loading the Marlin 2.0 folder AFTER I put the configs in the right place. It almost worked.
I now get an error - binary operator expected before "(".

Answer (score 1):

I have both the BTT SKR PRO v1.1 and the BTT SKR mini v1.1 (it is unclear which is meant by the OP), and for both you do not upload over the USB, you compile the software into a `firmware.bin` file which you place onto the microSD card. Once you power the board, the new firmware file will be installed onto your board.

Comment: It is the 1.1, not the pro. I got the right config but now get a new error.
It won't compile because it can't find the amd64 library.